# Is there a way to create a thread in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that creates a thread upon a message in a specific channel. If there is a way to create a thread in a text channel in discord.py, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, but with a catch.

**The current version of discord.py (1.0+) does not support threads**. But there is a beta version of discord.py 2.0 that allows users to use threads, but it is in beta and may be prone to bugs. Instead, **I recommend Pycord, which supports threads** and is a community-driven fork of discord 2.0 beta and is much better.

You can install Pycord by following instructions on the [Github Page](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord).

And to create a thread with Pycord you can use:

```py
await create_thread(*, name, auto_archive_duration=in-minutes)
```

You can view everything including how to create a thread in more detail on the [docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Message.create_thread).

Answer (score 3):

**As of writing this, the version of discord.py is v2.1**

First, I would grab the TextChannel that I am going to be working with, then I create the channel thread.

```
channel = client.get_channel(int(channel_id))
thread = await channel.create_thread(
    name="example",
    type=ChannelType.public_thread
)
```

Afterwards, I would send a message within the thread

```
await thread.send("This is an example message")
```

There are some other parameters that you can include in creating a channel thread, so be sure to check out the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=textchannel#discord.TextChannel.create_thread)